# ValueError: matplotlib display text must have all code points < 128 or use Unicode strings (Using a path)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a path for matplotlib. When I am trying to use `savefig()` method, there is appearing this error. `dirresoluc` and `cualtes` are defined in the code. Help me please.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
...
...
rutaaux = os.path.join(dirresoluc,cualtes+'.png')
plt.savefig(rutaaux, dpi=1500)
plt.close()

ValueError: matplotlib display text must have all code points < 128 or use 
Unicode strings
```

**UPDATE**
*cualtes
`ressolic=str(raw_input('\Type here your text: '))
 cualtes = ressolic`

*dirresoluc
`import os
 dirresoluc=r'ResolucionesEncontradasCREG\ResultadosHallados'
 if not os.path.exists(dirresoluc):
 os.makedirs(dirresoluc)`

Comment: Could you show how dirresoluc and cualtes are defined?

Comment: I have updated the post. Thanks.